# Probability that n random points on a sphere, divided by m planes, fall in the same hemisphere

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-geometry

What is the probability that n random points on a sphere, sliced by m planes passing through the center, all fall on the same hemisphere defined by one of the m planes? Assume that each plane is perpendicular to a vector from the center of the sphere to one corner of an embedded cube (m=8/2 or 4 unique planes), or in general, a 3D lattice with m=k^3 vertices where k is the number of levels in each dimension.

For example, 5 points are placed on a sphere divided into 14 regions by 4  planes.

This is a generalization of [Probability that $n$ random points on a circle, divided into $m$ fixed and equal sized slices are contained in less than $m/2$ adjacent slices.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076967/probability-that-n-random-points-on-a-circle-divided-into-m-fixed-and-equal)

Comment: The fact that you haven't had answers is maybe that your problem (very connected to the problem of "all points in "a" same hemisphere", without predefined planes) has not a unique answer because it depends on the relative positions of the planes...

Comment: Good point.  I added a constraint that the planes are arranged according to the corners of an embedded cube.