# Evaluating an infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}2^{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have been trying to find the sum of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}2^{n}}$$
but I couldn't find any methods (such as a fourier series) that seem to get me anywhere.

WolframAlpha gave $ \dfrac{\pi^2}{12}-\dfrac{ln^2(2)}{2},$ but how would one get to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better way to go about this is as follows. Put $g(x)=-\int_0^x\frac{\ln(1-t)}t\text dt$. As you know from the other answers, you are trying to compute $\frac 12g(1/2)$. Now prove that $g(x)+g(1-x)=g(1)-\ln(x)\ln(1-x)$ using the definition of $g$, a substitution and integration by parts. Then expand the Taylor series for the integrand of $g(1)$ and integrate term by term to get $g(1)=\sum_{n\ge1}n^{-2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$ (this is called the [Basel Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem?wprov=sfla1)). Finally, plug in $x=1/2$ and simplify.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}x^n$. Then 
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}x^{n-1} \\
xf'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}x^{n}\\
f'(x)+xf''(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

For simplicity let $y=f'(x)$. Then you need to solve:
$$y+xy'=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
or equivalently 
$$(xy)'=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

You can find $y=f'$ and hence $f$ from here. Plug in $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Please forgive me, because this is just a special value of the dilogarithm - see my answer.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel The issue is that using the dilogarithm is an overkill, Calculus students don't know what that is...

Comment: I would consider ODEs slightly out of reach for a high school student - although I learned them in high school, that was accelerated, and I learned them again in year 1 of my university course. Suppose I changed $2^n$ to $3^n$. Then the dilogarithm would be necessary. Besides, [if it works, use it](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2645953/357390).

Comment: @ParclyTaxel If you change $2^n$ to $3^n$ the same works, you just plugin $x=\frac{1}{3}$ at the end.... Besides, if my students would write that the answer is the dilogarithm function, WITHOUT details, I would not give them points for the solution. How is that different than plugging it into WolframAlpha ? Besides check the edit for the ODE part ;)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel As for the link you added, I fail to see the relevance to this post...

Comment: I prefer to be general in my answers wherever possible, looking to the literature if there is an answer there. That linked post shows how I hack the dilog's series representation (from the literature) to get a non-trivial result somewhat like the one here.

Comment: Won't both methods lead to having to find $\int_0^{1/2}  \ln(1-t)/t\text dt$ which is essentially what the third answer is doing?

Comment: @GuachoPerez Yes... It will lead to exactly the same answer...

Comment: But evaluating the dilogarithm is exactly as hard as computing the sum.

Comment: I'm left with $\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{-ln(1-x)}{x} dx}$ which I can only get close by integrating the series expansion to be around $0.5822,$ would there be a way to get exactly there without evaluating $\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)$?

Answer (score 1):

This sum is in fact the series representation of $\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)$, which has a [known closed form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html).

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n}$$
 Integrating from 0 to t we get
$$\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{(1-x)}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{t} x^{n}dx$$$$-\ln(1-t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n}}{n}$$
Dividing by t and integrating
$$\int_{0}^{0.5}-\frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}dt=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{0.5} \frac{t^{n-1}}{n}dt=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}2^{n}}$$
This on calculating is $$ \dfrac{\pi^2}{12}-\dfrac{ln^2(2)}{2},$$