# Probability that centre of circle is contained in triangle formed by three points on the circumference

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I have been looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268635/what-is-the-probability-that-the-center-of-the-circle-is-contained-within-the-tr/2741864#2741864).

I thought I knew a solution, but it appears to be at odds with the answers there. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my solution?

**My Attempted Solution.**

Without loss of generality, our circle is the unit circle and we can take one of the three points to be $(1,0)$. Let the other points be $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta), (\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$, $\theta,\phi\in(0,2\pi), \theta<\phi$.

In order for the centre to lie inside the triangle, we require $\pi<\phi<\pi+\theta$.

Hence, for fixed $\theta$, the probability that the centre lies inside the triangle is $\dfrac{\theta}{2\pi}$.

Now, we can average over all possible values of $\theta$:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\,d\theta=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\cdot\frac{4\pi^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

But according to the answers to the existing question, the correct probability is $\dfrac{1}{4}$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I don't follow how you get $\pi<\phi<\pi+\theta$  What if $\theta=\pi-\varepsilon, \phi = \pi+\varepsilon? $

Comment: @saulspatz Then still \pi<\phi<\pi+\theta$

Comment: https://youtu.be/OkmNXy7er84

Comment: you do not need to integrate to 2π

Comment: Yes, you are right.  You have exactly what I have written down.  I must be cross-eyed today.

Comment: I think I now understand the problem, from @quasi 's answer which was deleted - if $\pi<\theta<\phi<2\pi$, then the centre is not in the triangle, so we require $0<\theta<\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we can assume $0 < \theta < \pi$ (i.e., the second point is in the top half).

If the third point is in the top half, the probability of success is $0$, and if $\phi \ge \theta+\pi$, the probability of success is also $0$, so success requires $\pi < \phi < \theta + \pi$.

Hence as you argued, for fixed $\theta$, the probability of success is ${\large{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}}}$.

Then the integral becomes
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\,d\theta=\frac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

As already remarked, the issue lies in the integration bounds. Anyway such question and its generalization to the $n$-sphere can be solved by symmetry in a much slicker way. Assume that three points $A',B',C'$ have been chosen on the circumference. Let $A'',B'',C''$ be their antipodes. In any case, among the eight triangles $A^? B^? C^?$ two of them contain the center of the circle and six of them do not. The wanted probability is so $\frac{2}{8}=\frac{1}{4}$ since a point and its antipode are equally likely to be picked.