# randomly pick three points on a circle what is the probability that the resulting triangle contains the center of the circle

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Randomly pick three points on a unit circle what is the probability that the resulting triangle contains the center of the circle? This is the same question as asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268635/what-is-the-probability-that-the-center-of-the-circle-is-contained-within-a-tria). The intuition as explained is the following: fix a point $A$ on the circle, and another point $B$ on the circle, suppose that the arc length of $AB$ is $x$. if $x$ is strictly less than $\frac{1}{2}$, then the remaining point $C$ has to stay within an arc length of $x$. If $x > \frac{1}{2}$, then the remaining point $C$ has to stay within an arc length of $1 - x$. Thus the final probability can be calculated as $\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} x + \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1} 1 - x$.

However I am a struggling to make this argument formal. Basically, I can start by setting up three independent uniformly distributed random variable $X_1, X_2$ where $X_1$ is the arc length of $AB$ and $X_2$ is the position of the point $C$. Then I think the above argument correspond to making a statement about the probability of the desired event conditioning on arc length of $AB = x$.

Mathematically $P(\text{the triangle contains the center of the circle} | AB = x) = x$ if $x < \frac{1}{2}$. However, what does it mean to condition on an event of probability $0$?