# Probability of finding a point on or in an $n$-dimensional unit sphere

Tags: probability, statistics, geometric-probability

If a point is chosen at random in an $N$-dimensional unit sphere, what is the probability of falling inside the sphere of radius $0.99999999$? What if $N=3$, $N=10^{23}$, or $N = \infty $?

Okay, that is the question I have to address. I don't know how to bring the 2 concepts of Probability and $N$-dimensional hypersphere together to arrive at a solution. I found similar work [1](http://mathpages.com/home/kmath327/kmath327.htm), and [2](http://youtu.be/eEJtMFdkzzU). I still don't understand the underlying concept that would allow me to find $P(x,y)$.

Comment: [related material 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/172296/77120), [related material 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/185298)

Comment: One should not use lower-case $n$ and capital $N$ interchangeably.

Comment: This may help you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball

Comment: I will try to never make said error again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a uniform distribution,
the probability would be the ratio of the volumes.

In a $n$-dimensional space,
the volume of a $n$-sphere of radius $r$
is a constant times $r^n$.
Since we are dividing two volumes,
the constant goes away,
so the probability is
$r^n$,
where $r$ is your $0.999999$.

Various estimates can be made
depending on how close $r$ is to $1$
and how large $n$ is.

If $r = 1-c$ where $c$ is small,
this becomes
$(1-c)^n \approx 1-n c$
for $n$ small compared with $1/c$.

Since $(1-c)^n = e^{n \ln(1-c)}$,
if $n c^2$ is small,
$n \ln(1-c) \approx -nc$,
so
$(1-c)^n\approx e^{-nc}
$

If $r = 1-c/n$,
this becomes
$(1-c/n)^n \to e^{-c}$
as $n \to \infty$.

And so it goes.